# The composite function limit theorem proof

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, proof-writing

Let us define two functions:-

$$f(x)$$
$$g(x)$$

And now let us try to find the limit :-

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(g(x))$$
Assuming that all the limits mentioned below exist we can say:-
$$ \lim_{x \to c}g(x)=L$$

$$\lim_{x \to c}f(g(x))=\lim_{g(x) \to L} f(\lim_{x \to c}g(x))=\lim_{x \to L}f(x)$$

That is is just taking the limit of $f$ when the input is limit of $g$.

But why is it so why should we use the limit of $g$ as the input for $f$ according to me it is not equivalent to:-

$$\lim_{x\to c}(f \circ g)x$$

So why do we use it?

> Edit- After seeing the comments I think people do not understand what I am saying are not equivalent. I want to say according to me:-
> $$\lim_{x\to c}(f \circ g)x ≠ \lim_{x \to L}f(x)$$
> So why do we use it to find limits of composite functions?

Comment: ∘ is essentially just one function/map, which takes value (()) at  . Why would you think  (()) is different from (∘)()?

Comment: @StoneEcho No,I am not thinking that I am saying that  $$\lim_{x \to c}(f \circ g)x$$ is different from $$\lim_{x \to L}f(x)$$

Comment: Then what exactly do you think are not equivalent to each other?

Comment: @StoneEcho Can you check the edit and tell me if it's clear or not?

Comment: I get what you mean now, and I think that can be proved using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$. I'll get an answer up quick.

Comment: @StoneEcho Okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not true* that if $\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to L} f(x) = u$ then $\lim_{x \to c} f(g(x)) = u$.  Here is a counterexample.  Let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
4, &\text{if } x \ne 7,\\
3, &\text{if } x = 7,
\end{cases}
$$
and $g(x) = 7$.  Then $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 7$ and $\lim_{x \to 7} f(x) = 4$, but for all $x$, $f(g(x)) = f(7) = 3$, so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x)) = 3$.

Intuitively, here is the problem.  To simplify notation, let $y$ denote $g(x)$, so $f(g(x)) = f(y)$.  And let us rewrite $\lim_{x \to L} f(x)$ as $\lim_{y \to L} f(y)$ (they are the same).  Then $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = L$ means that if $x$ is close to $c$ *but not equal to $c$* then $y = g(x)$ is close to $L$.  And $\lim_{y \to L} f(y) = u$ means that if $y$ is close to $L$ *but not equal to $L$* then $f(y)$ is close to $u$.  The problem when trying to combine these is that if $x$ is close to $c$ but not equal to $c$, we know that $y$ is close to $L$, but we don't know that $y$ is not equal to $L$, so we can't apply $\lim_{y \to L} f(y) = u$.

In my calculus book (*Calculus: A Rigorous First Course*), I introduced the following notation.  If $y = g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = L$, many books would write "as $x \to c$, $y \to L$," but this notation leaves out the fact that $x$ can't be equal to $c$.  So in my book, I write "as $x \to c^{\ne}$, $y \to L$."  Using this notation, if $y = g(x)$, $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = L$, and $\lim_{y \to L} f(y) = u$, then we have: as $x \to c^{\ne}$, $y \to L$ and as $y \to L^{\ne}$, $f(y) \to u$.  But the mismatch between $y \to L^{\ne}$ and $y \to L$ means that these statements cannot be combined.

If you know that as $x \to c^{\ne}$, $y = g(x) \to L$ and as $y \to L$, $f(y) \to u$, then you can combine these statements and say that as $x \to c^{\ne}$, $f(g(x)) = f(y) \to u$.  This is the justification for the theorem, found in most calculus books, that if $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = L$, $f$ is continuous at $L$, and $f(L) = u$, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(g(x)) = u$.

If you know that as $x \to c^{\ne}$, $y = g(x) \to L^{\ne}$ and as $y \to L^{\ne}$, $f(y) \to u$, then you can also conclude that as $x \to c^{\ne}$, $f(g(x)) = f(y) \to u$, so $\lim_{x \to c} f(g(x)) = u$.  This shows that if $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = L$, $\lim_{y \to L} f(y) = u$, *and* for $x \ne c$, $g(x) \ne L$, then you can conclude that $\lim_{x \to c} f(g(x)) = u$.